# How to sum client totals across subsidiaries when # of subsidiaries varies?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Right now I have client and subsidiary info in one column and I have the column filtered for the clients only. In column B i have amount bought. I want to sum these amounts in column C, but because each client has a diff # of subsids I must do it manually

```
        A        B      C
1   
2   Client A           =SUM(B3:B6)
3     -Stuff    $$$
4     -Stuff    $$$
5     -Stuff    $$$
6     -Stuff    $$$
7   Client B           =SUM(B8:B43)
8     -Stuff    $$$
...
43    -Stuff    $$$
44  Client C           =SUM(B45:B58)
45    -Stuff    $$$
...
58    -Stuff    $$$
```

If there was a set distance between each client level I could write a formula and drag it down, but the varying number of subsidiaries means I have to do it manually. There's about 150 clients so I don't mind doing it manually but it's a waste of time if there's a more efficient method, and I will have more assignments like this in the future.

Comment: Can you get client in one column and subsidiary in another column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to seperate client and subsidiary into two columns so that your data looks like this:

[image: Before Pivot]

Then you can create a pivot table. (Insert > Pivot Table)  Here is a screenshot of my pivot table finalized with the criteria off to the right:

[image: After Pivot]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy solution, considering your last edit.
Just put the first client name in an empty row before your data and then put those formulas in as the second image

[image]

[image]

Comment: This could work but I have IDs instead of names so it's client 2,3,8,9 and subidiary 1398,2875,9383. If I created a concantenated combined key I could use a sumif with the criteria being the first letter matches the key, but this seems like more work than just summing them up.